# How to get PowerShell script execution error - System.Management.Automation.dll

Tags: c#, powershell

I execute a PowerShell script from C# code. I use [System.Management.Automation.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation.dll/10.0.10586) Nuget package. Although my script has an obvious error, `powerShell.Invoke()` returns no results, nor error messages.

```
using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShell.AddScript("an erroneous script");
    powerShell.Invoke(); // yields an empty PSObject list
}
```

How can I get a list of errors?

Comment: Does your script generate any exceptions? If there are some exceptions thrown, then you can investigate them further by looking at the `$Error` variable. For example `$Error[0].Exception.StackTrace` will show the stack trace for the latest error that got thrown.

Comment: `powerShell.Streams.Error`

Comment: @KimPihlström Yes, it does. I added `powerShell.AddScript("$Error")` before `Invoke` and got the `$Error` as a result. Thanks!

Comment: @PetSerAl You should put that as an answer